# Scala hex string to bytes

Tags: scala, protocol-buffers

Is there a neat way in Scala to convert a hexadecimally encoded `String` to a protobuf `ByteString` (and back again)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use (without additional dependencies) [`DatatypeConverter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html) as:

```scala
import com.google.protobuf.ByteString
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter
val hexString: String = "87C2D268483583714CD5"
```

```scala
val byteString: ByteString = ByteString.copyFrom(
  DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(hexString)
)
```

```scala
val originalString = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(byteString.toByteArray)
```

Comment: Why `akka.util.ByteString` though?

Comment: My bad, updated answer to use `com.google.protobuf.ByteString`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `java.math.BigInteger` to parse a `String`, get the `Array[Byte]` and from there turn it into a `ByteString`. Here would be the first step:

```
import java.math.BigInteger

val s = "f263575e7b00a977a8e9a37e08b9c215feb9bfb2f992b2b8f11e"

val bs = new BigInteger(s, 16).toByteArray
```

The content of `bs` is now:

```
Array(0, -14, 99, 87, 94, 123, 0, -87, 119, -88, -23, -93, 126, 8, -71, -62, 21, -2, -71, -65, -78, -7, -110, -78, -72, -15, 30)
```

You can then use (for example) the `copyFrom` method (JavaDoc [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/ByteString#copyFrom-byte:A-)) to turn it into a `ByteString`.

Comment: This will only work with up to 64bit data and for much smaller sizes it's wasteful.

Answer (score 2):

**Starting with Java 17,** you can use a standard API for parsing HEX strings to byte array.

```
import java.util.HexFormat

HexFormat.of.parseHex("d719af")
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the title of the question doesn't mention Protobuf, if anyone is looking for a solution that doesn't require any dependencies for converting a hex String to Seq[Byte] for any sized array: (don't forget to add input validation as necessarily)

```scala
val zeroChar: Byte = '0'.toByte
val aChar: Byte = 'a'.toByte

def toHex(bytes: Seq[Byte]): String = bytes.map(b => f"$b%02x").mkString

def toBytes(hex: String): Seq[Byte] = {

  val lowerHex = hex.toLowerCase

  val (result: Array[Byte], startOffset: Int) =
    if (lowerHex.length % 2 == 1) {

    // Odd
    val r = new Array[Byte]((lowerHex.length >> 1) + 1)
    r(0) = toNum(lowerHex(0))
    (r, 1)

  } else {

    // Even
    (new Array[Byte](lowerHex.length >> 1), 0)
  }

  var inputIndex = startOffset
  var outputIndex = startOffset
  while (outputIndex < result.length) {

    val byteValue = (toNum(lowerHex(inputIndex)) * 16) +
      toNum(lowerHex(inputIndex + 1))

    result(outputIndex) = byteValue.toByte

    inputIndex += 2
    outputIndex += 1
  }

  result
}

def toNum(lowerHexChar: Char): Byte =
  (if (lowerHexChar < 'a') lowerHexChar.toByte - zeroChar else 10 +
    lowerHexChar.toByte - aChar).toByte
```

https://scalafiddle.io/sf/PZPHBlT/2

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution without any dependency or intermediate object could be

```scala
def toBytes(hex: String): Seq[Byte] = {
  assert(hex.length % 2 == 0) // only manage canonical case
  hex.sliding(2, 2).map(Integer.parseInt(_, 16).toByte).toSeq
}

assert(toBytes("1234") == Seq[Byte](18,52))
```

[code online](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/snCNAm5ZS1ewRkO9b5MIgw)